# Can you explain these 2 SQL queries to me?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm studying for my DB exam which covers a lot of SQL statements I need to write by hand. Below is the schema diagram and solutions for 2 scenarios that were outlined in my book that don't seem to make sense to me.

[image]

**Q13: Retrieve the names of all employees in department 5 who work more than 10 hours per week on the ProductX project.**

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE,PROJECT, WORKS_ON
WHERE DNO = 5 AND PNAME = ‘PRODUCT X’ AND HOURS>10 AND ESSN=SSN;
```

Shouldn't the **WHERE** clause include **PNO = NUMBER** ? How would the **WORKS_ON** table know to reference the **PROJECT** table without including this? Is it because we reference the ESSN = SSN?

**Q1: Retrieve the name of each employee who has a dependent with the same first name and is the same sex as the employee.**

```
SELECT E.FNAME, E.LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E
WHERE E.SSN IN (SELECT D.ESSN FROM DEPENDENT AS D WHERE E.FNAME = D.DEPENDENT_NAME AND D.SEX = E.SEX);
```

I understand this query all the way up until the **WHERE** clause. I don't understand  what **E.SSN IN** is trying to do with the sub query ahead of it. If someone can explain this, that would be great.

Comment: Never use comma join syntax. And see correlated vs uncorellated subqueries.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, yes you guessed it right. There should be another clause as  **PNO = NUMBER**.

For second question, think of it this way: Select an employee where employee number[Ssn] **is in the list of** employeeIDs [Essn] returned by sub-query for each given employee number [Ssn]. This should work fine. But, because Essn and Dependant Name are both keys for the Dependent table, you can also use simple join statements and get it done. Read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

For Q13: You need to include one more condition in **WHERE** clause that tells the relation between **Works_on** and **Project**, which is

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE,PROJECT, WORKS_ON
WHERE Pno = Pnumber AND DNO = 5 AND PNAME = ‘PRODUCT X’ AND HOURS>10 AND ESSN=SSN;
```

Q1: uses **correlated sub-query**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.FNAME, E.LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON WO
ON WO.Essn = E.Ssn
INNER JOIN PROJECT P
ON P.Pnumber = WO.Pno
where E.DNO = 5 
and P.name = 'ProductX'
and WO.Hours > 10
```